# AutoMapper skip all members on source that are null

Tags: c#, automapper

given this mapping

```
_mapper.Map(personDto, person, opt => opt.ConfigureMap()
    .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null))
);
```

`person` before mapping

```
FirstName: "John"
LastName: "Doe"
Email: "John.Doe@gmail.com"
```

`personDto` before mapping

```
FirstName: "Jim"
LastName: "Denver"
Email: NULL
```

expected output `person`

```
FirstName: "Jim"
LastName: "Denver"
Email: "John.Doe@gmail.com"
```

actual output `person`

```
FirstName: "Jim"
LastName: "Denver"
Email: NULL
```

mapper came from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/43947731/3511012

---

Update, I also tried using `ResolveUsing` and it has the same output

```
_mapper.Map(personUpdateDto, person, opt => opt.ConfigureMap()
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.ResolveUsing((src, dest, srcMember, dstMember) => srcMember ?? dstMember))
);
```

---

Comment: This doesn't answer your question as it has to be configured for each member, but maybe it will help.  How about use null coalescing operator in the member map configuration. `.ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) => src.Email ?? dest.Email))`

Comment: I'm using `ForAllMembers` so it can't specifically look at `Email`. I did try an adaptation of your idea with `.ForAllMembers(opts => opts.ResolveUsing((src, dest, srcMember, dstMember) => srcMember ?? dstMember))` but that had the same effect as `Condition`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you have a predefined mapping from `PersonDto` to `Person` and trying to configure that mapping in the `Map` method. In that case, the code below really doesn't work as you want because the lambda in the `ForAllMembers` is never being called.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>());//.ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)));
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Snow" ,Email="test@mail.com"};
var personUpdateDto = new PersonDto { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Denver" };
var a = mapper.Map(personUpdateDto, person, opt => opt.ConfigureMap()
            .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) =>
            {
                return srcMember != null;
            }
            )));
```

But the code below works as you want:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>().ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)));
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Snow", Email = "test@mail.com" };
var personUpdateDto = new PersonDto { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Denver" };
var a = mapper.Map(personUpdateDto, person);
```

Another way to work with inline maps is to define empty mapper configuration and then add inline maps:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { });
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Snow", Email = "test@mail.com" };
var personUpdateDto = new PersonDto { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Denver" };
var a = mapper.Map(personUpdateDto, person,opts=>opts.ConfigureMap()
.ForAllMembers(opts2 => opts2.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) =>
{
    return srcMember != null;
}
)));
```

Comment: So passing `ConfigureMap` does not override the `MapperConfiguration`?

Comment: @stackoverfloweth seems to be so.

Comment: that's unfortunate. I was hoping to use this solution so that the choice of having `NULL` override is set when calling map

Comment: @stackoverfloweth also you can define MapperConfiguration without predefined maps like `var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { });` and then add inline mappings. In this case code works as you want.