# Workaround for AutoMapper issue #3926?

Tags: c#, automapper

[AutoMapper issue #3962](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3926) was closed and locked without explanation or resolution. (In fact, *all* AutoMapper issues are being treated this way. The maintainer is directing people here.)

To summarize the issue, `IMemberConfigurationExpression.Condition` receives a `Func<TSrc, TDest, object, bool>`. The third parameter is the value of the source member being visited. For example:

```
public static class IMappingExpressionExtensions
{
    public static void Coalesce<Src, Dst>(this IMappingExpression<Src, Dst> exp)
    {
        exp.ForAllMembers(cfg => cfg.Condition((src, dst, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
    }
}
```

When the source member is a reference type and its value is null, `srcMember` is null as expected. But when the source member is a `Nullable<T>` without a value, `srcMember` is unexpectedly `default(T)` instead of null.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Progman Done. I just found [another closed issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2999) that references [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137405/how-to-set-automapper-ignore-null). Apparently this is a common gotcha. Still looking into whether my requirements are the same and whether any of those solutions work.

Comment: And [another closed issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1703). This is apparently a very common developer expectation, but the AutoMapper devs won't meet the expectation because it would be a breaking change.

Comment: It's becoming clear that the developer [doesn't understand the problem](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1703#issuecomment-265411448) and enjoys throwing people crumbs and being dismissive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heart of the matter is that `Condition` is called *after* the source member has been converted to the destination member type. This is why `Condition` works as expected for reference types, and even for `Nullable<T>` to `Nullable<T>`, but not `Nullable<T>` to `T`.

If all properties of `TSrc` map to properties of `TDst` with the same names, the following solution completely replaces `Condition`, producing the expected behavior for reference to reference, `Nullable<T>` to `Nullable<T>`, and `Nullable<T>` to `T`. Despite involving reflection and boxing, it seems to be quite fast.

```
public static void Coalesce<TSrc, TDst>(this IMappingExpression<TSrc, TDst> mapExp)
{
    foreach (var srcProp in typeof(TSrc).GetProperties())
    {
        mapExp.ForMember(srcProp.Name, mapExp => mapExp.PreCondition((o, _) => srcProp.GetValue(o) != null));
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, and you can live with changing the mapping of `Nullable<T>` to `T` for *all* mappings, you can replace the default type converter for `<T?,T>` with one that "converts" a null `Nullable<T>` into the destination value.

```
public class CoalescingTypeConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<T?, T> where T : struct
{
    public T Convert(T? source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source ?? destination;
    }
}
```

```
public static class IMapperConfigurationExpressionExtensions
{
    public static void CoalesceNullable<T>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg) where T : struct
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<T?, T>().ConvertUsing<CoalescingTypeConverter<T>>();
    }
}
```

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CoalesceNullable<int>();
    cfg.CoalesceNullable<bool>();
    // etc.
}
```