# AutoMapper Ignore(not map) all null values

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapping, automapper

I'm using automapper v11 (C# net6) I would like to Ignore(not map) all null values for all fields.

Here an example

```
class SrcExample
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}

class DestExample
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var map = CreateMap<SrcExample, DestExample>();
map.ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```

I'm trying to Ignore(not map) all null values using `opts.Condition` but it only works for **strings**.

For **int?** I got `srcMember = 0` instead of `srcMember = null`. Seems like Automapper uses default int value as srcMember value.

Why Automapper behaves this way?

Is there a way (using automapper) to Ignore(not map) all null values for all fields.

This question ([How to ignore null values for all source members during mapping in Automapper 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947475/how-to-ignore-null-values-for-all-source-members-during-mapping-in-automapper-6)) do not resolve the problem, due to the `set` method on the destination class is called anyway, (Here an example of how `set` method is called  https://dotnetfiddle.net/1grZkZ) I want to avoid `set` method being called. I want to completely ignore the map when the source value is null.

Comment: In your destination class the `Age` property is `int` instead of `int?`. `int` default value is 0.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos  Thanks for the comment. The source class is `int?` and the value of `Age` is `null`, so `srcMember` should be `null` not 0 on the `Condition`. I want to not map if the source value is null. The destination could be anything, right?

Comment: Set `UseDestinationValue` for `Age`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I want to not map all properties with values = `null`, not just `Age`. Could you please give an example of how could I use `UseDestinationValue` in order to do that. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why did this question get a -1? Isn't it clear enough? Is there a simple solution? (Which by the way nobody has answered it) I did a research and I couldn't find a solution for this. Not sure why this questions has -1. Any help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore null values for all source members during mapping in Automapper 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947475/how-to-ignore-null-values-for-all-source-members-during-mapping-in-automapper-6). Second answer has solution for exactly your problem.

Comment: And here is a dotnetfiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WrfKgm

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Thanks for the comment. Here the same dotnetfiddle example you gave me (with a Console.WriteLine on the `set` methods): https://dotnetfiddle.net/1grZkZ
The `set` method for `int` (`Age`) is still called, and that is want I want to avoid. I want to ignore(no map) null values.