Automapping problem when i try to map the collection from one entity to another
I'm using automapper to map two objects that have the same class ( .Map(Entity,Entity) ) like this.
The problem is when i'm trying to map the collection from the first entity to the second one. I get the NullReferenceException .
The moment that i retrieve my entity from the database , the associated property is set to null ( because i allowed it to be null) .
How to map a collection to another even when one of them is null?
This is what i tried
  // here i retrieve the user from the DB
            var currentUser = await extendedRepository.GetByTokenAsync(changePasswordDto.TokenProp);

            if (currentUser == null)
            {
                throw new DbUpdateException("User not found");
            }
            
          
            Console.WriteLine("inainte Adrese conturi in current user : " + currentUser.AdreseConturi); // here i get null
            
            // this mapper works 
            // updatedUser.AdreseConturi is not null ( i'm using the constructor to map) , even tho currentUser is null
            var updatedUser = _mapper.Map<Conturi>(currentUser,
                opt => opt.Items["NewPassword"] = changePasswordDto.NewHashedPasswordProp);
  
            ICollection<Adrese>? adreses = currentUser.AdreseConturi; // this is null , set only for testing purpose to see the value
            // and when i try to map here , i get the NullReferenceException from the AdreseConturi 
            _mapper.Map(updatedUser, currentUser);

This is my mappers profile:
// the entity to entity simpler mapper
CreateMap<Conturi, Conturi>()
            .ForAllMembers(options => options.Ignore());

// the entity to entity mapper where i needed to change passwords 
CreateMap<Conturi, Conturi>()
            .ConstructUsing((src, context) =>
            {
                var newPassword = context.Items.TryGetValue("NewPassword", out var newPasswordObj) ? newPasswordObj as string : src.Parola;
                
                return new Conturi(
                    src.Nume,
                    src.Prenume,
                    src.Gen,
                    src.NrTelefon,
                    src.Username,
                    src.Email,
                    newPassword,
                    src.DataCreare,
                    src.CodActivare,
                    src.Verificat,
                    src.Rol,
                    src.OraLinkConfirmare,
                    src.AdreseConturi
                );
                
            });

---
And this is my entity:
public  class Conturi : ICloneable
{
    /* other atributes, irrelevant for the problem */ 

    public  ICollection<Adrese>? AdreseConturi { get;}

    public Conturi()
    {
        
    }

    public Conturi(string? nume, string? prenume, bool? gen, string? nrTelefon, string username, 
                   string email, string parola, DateTime? dataCreare, 
                   string codActivare, bool verificat, string rol ,DateTime oraLinkConfirmare,ICollection<Adrese>? adreseConturi)
    {
        Nume = nume;
        Prenume = prenume;
        Gen = gen;
        NrTelefon = nrTelefon;
        Username = username;
        Email = email;
        Parola = parola;
        DataCreare = dataCreare;
        CodActivare = codActivare;
        Verificat = verificat;
        Rol = rol;
        OraLinkConfirmare = oraLinkConfirmare;
        AdreseConturi = adreseConturi == null ? new HashSet<Adrese>() : new HashSet<Adrese>(adreseConturi);
       
    }

And this is the error :
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Conturi -> Conturi
E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.UserRelatedModels.Conturi -> E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.UserRelatedModels.Conturi

Type Map configuration:
Conturi -> Conturi
E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.UserRelatedModels.Conturi -> E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.UserRelatedModels.Conturi

Destination Member:
AdreseConturi

 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
/* rest of the error */

---
How can i get past that error or how can i solve it  , and please if you're kindly enough to explain me where is the problem and make me understand it. Thank you very much!
!!!!! UPDATE
my property on AdreseConturi does not have a setter. I looked for other tricks , found BeforeMap() but i do not want to use a setter on that property. I even tried Configuration , to no avail .
!!! NEW UPDATE
i put a setter on the property and moved on . Now the mapper where i'm using the constructor is not copying the new password aparently . I even consoled logged it inside the mapper , and the new password is received , but is not assigned when i'm creating the object . Weird things are happening and i dont get why they are.

You probably want to use Condition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947475/how-to-ignore-null-values-for-all-source-members-during-mapping-in-automapper-6

and so the mapping would be possible only if the user has some addresses saved on his account right ?

You could do something like
ICollection<Adrese>? adreses = ((currentUser.AdreseConturi != null) ? currentUser.AdreseConturi : somefallback);

but then, of course, you will need to define somefallback. It could be an empty collection, or even updatedUser.AdreseConturi, depending on what fits best your needs.
